# Red 5 Video recorder. Installer.swf not working

Tags: red5, fla

I have installed Red (setup-Red5-1.0.0-RC2-java6) on my windows xp. Red5 server running proper. but installer.swf not able to connect. also getting 404 error while installing demos. demos directory is not at the location as well.

any Idea what could have cause this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the 0.9.1 build. Also your firewall should allow listening on port 5080 (default for red5).
As an alternative try manually installing the demos from the source trunk and restart the server.